# Maven-compiler-plugin:3.3: testCompile (default-testCompile) failing on compile Attribute$Error cannot be cast to Attribute$Class

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I've been searching high and low for the solution to this problem, but I can't seem to be able to find the right answer. I believe, I have a unique situation, and thus the problem might be even more difficult to solve.
At the core of the problem, is this error message I'm getting when run `mvn test` command:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project DriveServiceFitnesse: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute$Error cannot be cast to com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute$Class -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

However `mvn compile` doesn't through the error. 
But since I need mvn test to generate the test sources, my test isn't actually working. I know this because, when I run my test, I get this error:

```
    Error:java: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute$Error cannot be cast to 
com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute$Class
```

The project used to compile and run without issues. This issue arose when I tried to convert my project from Maven to Gradle. I ran into similar issues, so I closed the branch out and pulled down my original working code/project, and now I can't seem to fix it.

Any help on this matter would be highly appreciated. I will post my pom.xml file if that might help.

*Edit: Based on a suggestion I'm pasting in the stacktrace message I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project DriveServiceFitnesse: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute$Error cannot be cast to com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute$Class -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project DriveServiceFitnesse: Fatal error compiling
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:836)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo.execute(TestCompilerMojo.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
```

Comment: Try mvn test -X and see the exact stacktrace.

Comment: Oh I did, and the stacktrace didn't help much either. pasting in the stacktrace in another reply

Comment: What are the Maven and Java versions you run on?

Comment: maven is 3.3.3 and java is 1.7.0.71

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this error. Was an oversight on my part. The issue was that for some reason, a local jar I had imported using the "Project Structure" (in intellij) had somehow expired, i.e. the library was still listed, but wasn't being pulled into the project properly. I deleted the reference and reimported and things seemed to work... sigh.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried multiple solutions for finding the root cause of the issue and observed that my machine is taking too long for compiling the classes than the usual time so we tried increasing the maxmem option in configuration.

I have changed my compiler-plugin maxmem option from **1024m to 2048m** and this resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue was caused by me trying to use a "default maven profile" in my pom.xml,  along with another e2e test profile .  I switched back to a regular pom and it works now.    Still not sure the actual cause.